# How to kill a background process in linux

Tags: linux, process, rpc

I am doing rpc connection between two computers. I have started a process ./server & in one computer (linux) and forgot to kill. Now when I try to establish the connection again, it says RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Timed out. because the old process is still running in the background. How do I kill it?

Answer (score 2):

First get the process id of that job

```
$ pgrep wget
```

then kill it..

```
$ kill<pid>
```

Comment: Or simply `pkill` with the name of the process

Comment: I have always enjoyed this if a simple kill 15 doesn't work. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process

Comment: also if you want to force the process to end, you can use -9 switch: kill -9 pid. type kill -l to display all kill switches